# Dll is getting missed from Webapplication in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, tfs, azure-pipelines

I have one Website, we are using VSO/TFS for the code repository, build & release through VSO. Issue is, when ever reference being added from Nuget manager & we push the code to VSO repository, Build is failing with the missing reference. Because, in the website root file(.sln) the reference is not being updated. So each time we clean & rebuild the solution reference is missing.

We tried with creating a Reference folder  inside the website & putting all the Dll into it & referencing from there, but still it failing.

Any suggestion how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Are you running a NuGet package restore during your build?

Comment: Yes, Nuget task is being added in the Build template.

Comment: Does the output of the task report any errors?

Comment: Share detail build log here or on the OneDrive, also provide the detail steps of your build definition.

Comment: Its not possible to share the log, where as its like respective dll is missing. e.g. Newtonsoft dll missing.

Comment: Can you reproduce that issue with a new project? Do you check in changes of packages.config file?